# Add custom field when mint new ERC721 token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

i'm using the ECR721 preset smart contract from Openzeppelin for studying.

I would like to add a new field when i mint new token to store a string (public).

At the moment there is only the field "to:address" (screenshot below)

[image: mint new token]

I'm sure i need to add something in the mint function:

[image: mint function]

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to store the message on blockchain is to emit an event. Event is permanently stored and publicly readable.

1. Define new `MintMessage` event outside the `mint()` function. I don't recommend expanding the default `Transfer` event that is used during minting, because external tools (such as Etherscan) might ignore the non-standard event and not show minted tokens as a result.
2. Add a new argument to the `mint()` function
3. Emit the `MintMessage` event within the `mint()` function

```
event MintMessage(string message);

function mint(address to, string message) public virtual {
   // keep the rest of your function as is
   // add a new line emiting the event to the end of the function
   emit MintMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Not the original author: The important distinction is that other smart contracts cannot read events, it is visible only on the client-side. So the suitability of the event depends on the use case of the string - whether it is only client consumable information or whether smart contracts might check this string in the some point of the future.